# Java parse a string into double

Tags: java

How do I parse this Double in string `"00034800"` into a Double value? The last 2 digits are actually decimal point, so the result I am looking for is `348.00`. Is there a such format I can use with Decimal Format?

Comment: `Double.parseDouble("00034800") / 100` ?

Comment: Are the last two digits always decimal point values?

Comment: @Aashray Yes, they are

Comment: @mshsayem You need `100.0` or you'll get the truncated value if it's something like `"00034856"`

Comment: Then @Brain's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well...

```
String s = "00034800";
double d = Double.parseDouble(s) / 100.0;
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(d));
```

Comment: You may also like to catch NumberFormatException if you are not using a static string, ie from input or such

Answer (score 4):

[Java Double has a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double%28java.lang.String%29) that takes a String.

You can do:

```
 Double d = new Double("00034800");
```

And then

```
 double myval = d.doubleValue() / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can parse it as

```
    double d = Double.parseDouble("00034800") / 100;
```

and print it as

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", d);
```

Comment: You need `100.0` or you'll get the truncated value if it's something like `"00034856"` (how many times do I need to post this..?)